# Cognos: Count the number of occurences of a distinct id

Tags: count, case, distinct, cognos

I'm making a report in Cognos Report Studio and I'm having abit of trouble getting a count taht I need. What I need to do is count the number of IDs for a department. But I need to split the count between initiated and completed. If an ID occures more than once, it is to be counted as completed. The others, of course, will be initiated. So I'm trying to count the number of ID occurences for a distinct ID. Here is the query I've made in SQl Developer:

```
SELECT
COUNT((CASE WHEN COUNT(S.RFP_ID) > 8 THEN MAX(CT.GCT_STATUS_HISTORY_CLOSE_DT) END)) AS "Sales Admin Completed"
,COUNT((CASE WHEN COUNT(S.RFP_ID) = 8 THEN MIN(CT.GCT_STATUS_HISTORY_OPEN_DT) END)) as "Sales Admin Initiated"
FROM 
ADM.B_RFP_WC_COVERAGE_DIM S
JOIN ADM.B_GROUP_CHANGE_REQUEST_DIM CR 
ON S. RFP_ID = CR.GCR_RFP_ID 
JOIN ADM.GROUP_CHANGE_TASK_FACT CT 
ON CR.GROUP_CHANGE_REQUEST_KEY = CT.GROUP_CHANGE_REQUEST_KEY 
JOIN ADM.B_DEPARTMENT_DIM D 
ON D.DEPARTMENT_KEY = CT.DEPARTMENT_RESP_KEY
WHERE CR.GCR_CHANGE_TYPE_ID = '20'
AND S.RFP_LOB_IND = 'WC'
AND S.RFP_AUDIT_IND = 'N'
AND CR.GCR_RECEIVED_DT BETWEEN '01-JAN-13' AND '31-DEC-13'
AND D.DEPARTMENT_DESC = 'Sales'
AND CT.GCT_STATUS_IND = 'C' 
GROUP BY S.RFP_ID ;
```

Now this works. But I'm not sure how to translate taht into Cognos. I tried doing a CASE taht looked liek this(this code is using basic names such as dept instead of D.DEPARTMENT_DESC):

```
 CASE WHEN dept = 'Sales' AND count(ID for {DISTINCT ID}) > 1 THEN count(distinct ID)END)
```

I'm using count(distinct ID) instead of count(maximum(close_date)). But the results would be the same anyway. The "AND" is where I think its being lost. It obviously isn't the proper way to count occurences. But I'm hoping I'm close. Is there a way to do this with a CASE? Or at all?

--EDIT--
To make my question more clear, here is an example:

Say I have this data in my table

```
ID
---
1
2
3
4
2
5
5
6
2
```

My desired count output would be:

```
Initiated   Completed
---------   ---------
    4           2
```

This is because two of the distinct IDs (2 and 5) occure more than once. So they are counted as Completed. The ones that occure only once are counted as Initiated. I am able to do this in SQl Dev, but I can't figure out how to do this in Cognos Report Studio. I hope this helps to better explaine my issue.

Comment: "But I'm not sure how to translate taht into Cognos". What exactly do you mean by this?

Comment: I don't know how to use cognos to perform the same task I did in the SQL Dev.

Comment: In Report Studio, go into the query pane in report studio, drop in a SQL element and put your query in there. OR model it properly in Framework Manager so that you can just drag and drop query subjects and it will build the SQL for you.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I didn't quite got it originally, amending the answer.

But it's still easiest to do with 2 queries in Report Studio. Key moment is that you can use a query as a source for another query, guaranteeing proper group by's and calculations.

So if you have ID list in the table in Report Studio you create:

Query 1 with dataitems:

- ID,
- count(*) or count (1) as count_occurences
- status (initiated or completed) with a formula: if (count_occurences > 1) then ('completed') else ('initiated').

After that you create a query 2 using query one as source with just 2 data items:

- [Query1].[Status]
- Count with formula: count([Query1].[ID])

That will give you the result you're after. 

 
Here's a link to doco on how to nest queries:
http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cx/v10r1m0/topic/com.ibm.swg.ba.cognos.ug_cr_rptstd.10.1.0.doc/c_cr_rptstd_wrkdat_working_with_queries_rel.html?path=3_3_10_6#cr_rptstd_wrkdat_working_with_queries_rel

Comment: Sorry it took so long for me to comment. I'm not really sure what you're telling me to do. But I will edit my question to help clearify.